# Unexplained iOS ignoring CSS margins

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries

I cannot figure out why my page is ignoring margins on this page on an iPhone 5 (iOS 8) on Chrome!

It seems that media queries are being ignored, yet I have have the viewport meta tag!  What's going on?

Here is the site:

http://ec2-54-183-220-135.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/spitz/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine?

However, usually when media queries are not working, it might be because other css is overriding.

Remember to always have media queries below your general css rules. If there is no spesific rule in your media query, the properties further up your css-sheet will be applied.

Comment: Did you look at it on an actual phone?  The media queries are being ignored, no other CSS is overriding.